# Using a character vector to reference and modify other objects

Tags: r

So, I have a large list of nonstandardized vector names that I'm trying to work with, all of which need to be manipulated in the same way and I'm having a problem finding a way to work with them en masse.  I figure what I can do is combine all of the different objects into one big vector of object names and work through the resulting list iteratively using the character strings as pointers to the actual variables.

Here's a crude example of the kind of setup I'm trying to work with:

```
a <- c(1, 2)
b <- c(3, 4)
c <- c("a", "b")
...
z <- vector()

varlist <- ls(all = TRUE)
```

I want to be able to use varlist[i] to be able to reference each of the variables in turn to perform some sort of operations on them and then store the result of that operation back in that same object.

So far referencing them hasn't been a problem, as I can use `eval(as.symbol(varlist[i]))` to display the contents of a given object in that list.  The problem is, trying to use the same method to store the new values (example below) doesn't seem to work.

```
as.symbol(varlist[i]) <- "New Value"
eval(as.symbol(varlist[i] <- "New Value"
```

In each of these cases, it seems like the `<-` is combined with the outermost function to form a function that doesn't exist.  So in the case of the first answer, we get `Error in as.symbol(varlist[i]) <- "New Value" : could not find function "as.symbol<-"` and in the second we get `could not find function "eval<-"`.

How can I store new data in the listed variables, and (since I'm pretty new to this still) is there a better way to do these types of mass computations?

Comment: Very likely your setup is kind of a mess and you should worry of change it from the beginning. You rather should have a named list. That said, look at `?assign` and `?get`. I add that using `assign` in most cases is a terribad practice.

Comment: Just do `varlist <- mget(varlist)` and work with the resulting list. Alternatively, `.GlobalEnv[[varlist[i]]]`. PS: Note that `ls(all = TRUE)` includes invisible objects such as the random seed.

Comment: Since you are still new to this, then I strongly suggest not going down this path any further. It is not a good idea to write R code like this. You should work with related data inside lists rather than create a bunch of variables in your global environment. You should almost never have to use `eval()` (at least not when starting out). It would be better to give a practical example of why you think this is necessary and we could show a more R-like way to do things.

Comment: @Roland Thanks!  It's good to know, even though I don't use `ls(all = TRUE)` in the actual code, just in this example.  I didn't realize it was so fraught.

Comment: @MrFlick I actually started out trying to work with a 1xAWholeLot tibble where each column was named with the variable name and then the contents of the cell [1,i] was a list of the variable contents.  This made it easy to access the contents but whenever I tried to add an additional value to the list it would say that there weren't enough rows in the column for me to put it in so I switched to this.  Will the result of `varlist <- mget(varlist)` that @Roland was talking about make a named list like you're talking about?

Comment: Well , mget() will collect variables into a list but it would be better not to create those separate variables in the first place. A more generic list would probably be better than a tibble for general data storage rather than tabular data.

Comment: @MrFlick That's doing exactly what I wanted, thanks!